# Get the index of duplicate values except the first

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

Below is an example array:

```js
const attD = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3]
```

How can we get the index of the duplicate values from this array? In this example, 3 is repeated thrice. So, I want to get the index 4, index 5 as these are duplicated at that positions (ignoring the first occurrence).

I have tried the below code, but it is giving me values. Instead, I need the index.

```js
const findDuplicates = attD => attD.filter((item, index) => attD.indexOf(item) !== index);
const duplicates = findDuplicates(attD);
console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. With `.map()`, add the index of duplicated values into the array. For non-duplicate value, will be added with `undefined` value *[Will be filtered in Step 2]*.
2. With `.filter()`, remove the value which is `undefined` from the array.

```js
const attD = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3];

const findDuplicates = attD => attD.map((item, index) => {
  if (attD.indexOf(item) !== index)
    return index;
}).filter(x => x);  // Equivalent to .filter(x => x != undefined || x != null)

const duplicates = findDuplicates(attD);
console.log(duplicates);
```